# Computer fully restarts with no POST under any significant load

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, computer-building

Specs: i5 3570k GTX 670 Corsair HX750 PSU

I built my desktop a few years back and it has worked like a charm up until the past week. Whenever I try to play any game, besides non-intensive stuff like league or terraria, anywhere from 2/3 mins to 30 mins or so it will run fine and then suddenly completely power off as if I had pulled the plug. The restarts seem very random as I have played the witcher 3 @ medium graphics for close to 30 mins while ARK on the lowest possible settings has restarted immediately after the loading screen.

I figured it was either CPU/GPU/PSU, but my temps seem fine for gpu and cpu (50-70 C and 30-40 C respectively). The PSU was gold rated and I thought at the time was something that was going to hold up well. I was on windows 110 preview and assumed it was a driver issue, but I have went back to windows 7 pro and am having the same kind of problem. I don't have another PSU at the moment to test it out or any kind of voltage reader. Any suggestions? I am hesitant to RMA the PSU because that involves either #1 being out of commision for a week plus or #2 having them put a hold on my card and then charging me should the PSU not be the issue. Want to have a bit better of an idea of where to proceed before I spend any money.

Thanks

Comment: So long as you're certain all the airflows are clear - including inside the GPU casing where you don't normally see; then the next obvious probable cause is the PSU. Capacitors get 'tired' over time. How old is the PSU? 'a few years' same as the rest of the machine? - then I wouldn't waste your time trying to RMA it. Might be cheaper to get a repair shop to test it, if you don't have spares to swap in.

Comment: Airflow could be a bit better, but if temps are fine is that an issue still? And yes all components are around 3-4 years old I think maybe 2-3 minimum. PSU has 7 year warranty available.

Comment: If airflow is poor, everything's working harder to keep those temps down, so more stress on the PSU. I'd either get it tested locally, or risk an RMA

Comment: The temperatures that you mentioned for CPU and GPU, are those load or idle temperatures? 30-40 C for the GTX 670 looks like its idle temperature. Whereas 50-70 C (a very wide range though) looks quite high for the i5 3570K, if it is its idle temperature.

Comment: CPU was the 30 idle 40 load  and GPU was 50 idle 70 load